# knockout "with" binding not working properly

Tags: knockout.js, hottowel

```
   <div data-bind="with: project"> 
     <div>
       <label>Name</label>
       <input class="inputControl" data-bind="value: name"/>
     </div>
     <div>
        <label>Id</label>
        <input class="inputControl" data-bind="value: id"/>
      </div>
   </div>
```

In this code, 'project' is an observable variable and it has 2 properties i.e. name and id.
'name' and 'id' fields are updating according to 'project' observable variable.
but when we redirect to other page and come back on same page, then 'name' and 'id' fields are not updating even 'project' is updating.
Please let us know for any suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To use name and id values in view, they are should be observables.

For example:

```
function projectViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable();
    self.id= ko.observable();
}

function vm() {
    var self = this;
    self.project = ko.observable(new projectViewModel());
}
```

Comment: Alexander: name and id fields are also observables and it works fine until we don't redirect to other page. but once we redirect to other page and come back on same page then these field are not updating even though 'project' is updating.